# I'm confused with one conditional probability problem

Tags: probability, statistics

everyone! I'm confused with the definition of conditional probability.
Assume we have one continuous random variable X and one discrete variable Y. 
I think $P(X>x|Y=y) = \int_{t=x}^\infty f(X=t|Y=y)\operatorname d t$. Right?

But, to compute $P(Y=y|X>x)$, can I use $\int_{t=x}^\infty f(Y=y|X=t)\operatorname d t$? I don't think so. Is there a way to solve it? I do appreciate your help!

Comment: Please read [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to format math expressions.

Comment: f(X=t|Y=y) is the conditional probabilty of X give Y.

Comment: Thank you! But I still couldn't do it in the right way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assume we have one continuous random variable X and one discrete variable Y. I think P(X>x|Y=y) = integral of f(X=t|Y=y) w.r.t. t (from x to infinite). Right?

Right. The conditional probability mass of $X>x$ given $Y=y$ is the integral of the probability density : $$\mathsf P(X>x\mid Y=y) =\int_x^\infty f(X=t\mid Y=y)\operatorname dt$$

> But, to compute P(Y=y|X>x), can I take integral of P(Y=y|X=t) w.r.t t (from x to infinite)? I don't think so.

Right, it's not. The conditional probability of $Y$ given $X>x$ is evaluated by Bayes' rule.

$$ \mathsf P(Y=y\mid X>x) = \frac{\mathsf P(X>x\mid Y=y)\mathsf P(Y=y)}{\mathsf P(X>x)}
$$

---

NB: I've edited the answer to match the edited question: Where $Y$ is discrete and $X$ is continuous.

Comment: I guess the OP referred to the *probability* $P(Y=y|X>x)$ instead of the PDF.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: P(Y=y|X>x) is the probabilty of Y=y given X>x. It's not the PDF. But it can still be computed by the bayes' rule, right?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that a *continuous* random $Y$ variable assumes exactly a given value $y$ is always zero.

EDIT: after the question was changed such that $Y$ is *discrete* (instead of continuous), Graham Kemp's answer actually answers the question.

Comment: I agree with you on that. P(Y=y)=0. But in f(X=t|Y=y), I'm trying to say the conditional probability of X give Y=y. Maybe I could use a better presentation.

Comment: @user36048 What Matt means I think is that $P(Y=y|X>x)=0$.

Comment: I see your point. It's my mistake. Y is supposed to be discrete random variable... I'll edit the question.

Comment: Sorry Matt! I didn't get you at first.